# Plotting the Likelihood of a Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: r, data-visualization, likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

```
likelihood = function(x, theta)
{
  likeli = (theta)^{sum(x)}*(1 - theta)^{length(x)-sum(x)}
  return(likeli)
}

data = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
         1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)

theta = seq(0, 1, 0.1)
like = rep(0, length(theta))

for(i in 1:length(theta)) 
  {
  like[i] = likelihood(theta[i], data)
}

plot(theta, like, type = "l")
```

The above is the code I wrote to try and plot the likelihood of observed data from a Bernoulli distribution as a function of $\theta$. I got the following output:

[image]

Is this correct? It looks very wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula in likelihood is correct, but the bigger your data set gets, the more problems you're going to have with numerical underflow. That's why so many of the points in your graph are being plotted as a $0$ on the y-axis. Recall that a joint pmf is the probability that $X_1 = x_1$ *and* $X_2 = x_2$ *and* ... That can get to be a very tiny event.

Try using the log likelihood instead. The log of a super small number is just really negative, so the computer will have no difficulty storing that in a floating point number.

```
log.likelihood <- function(data, theta){
  sum(dbinom(x = data, size = 1, prob = theta, log = T))
}
```

The plot will look a little nicer:

```
theta = seq(0, 1, 0.01)
lls <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(theta))
for(i in 1:length(theta))
  lls[i] <- log.likelihood(data, theta[i])
plot(theta, lls, type = "l")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It was very nice of you to help me. However, I am supposed to only plot the likelihood and not the log of the likelihood... I feel like the distribution plot is wrong. Are you saying that although it looks weird, it is correct?

Comment: Try this: `plot(theta, exp(lls), type = "l")` See how it's more curvy?

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. I was reading Doing Bayesian Data Analysis by John Kruschke and ran into this post. I might be wrong, but here are my thoughts.

I am assuming you don't care about the exact order of your 0's and 1's in your data, rather only the counts.

First, specify the data. We have 21 1's and 9 0's, which totals at N = 30.

```
# data, z = 21, N = 30
data = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)
```

Next, lets define the likelihood function. We calculate the number of 1's (z) and the total length of the data (N). Then, the uncommented lik specifies the probability for a set of outcomes y_i, where y_i specifies a single outcome in your data.

The other lik (commented out) specifies a probability from a binomial distribution, where the data is z (21 1's), number of trials is N (30) and the probability is theta. This is now different from the previous lik, because it takes into account combinatorics, namely how many times you can get 21 1's in 30 trials with a given theta. These lik's differ only in the combinatoric term N over z which is a constant and thus doesn't affect the shape of the curve.

```
likelihood <- function(data, theta){
z <- sum(data)
N <- length(data)
lik <- theta^z * (1-theta)^(N-z) # likelihood for plotting
#lik <- dbinom(x = z, size = N, prob = theta, log = F)
return(lik)
}
```

You then specify everything basically the same as in the previous post.

```
theta = seq(0, 1, 0.01)
lls <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = length(theta))

for(i in 1:length(theta)) {
  lls[i] <- likelihood(data, theta[i])
}

plot(theta, lls, type = "l")
```

The first likelihood gives you

[image: First likelihood]

And the second likelihood gives you

[image]

As you can see, the shapes are identical and thus the inference is identical also. The only difference is the y-axis scale. The maximum is found at theta = 0.7, which is the proportion of 1's in your data.